# Overload vector subscript operator to take a char * or string

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, stdvector

I am trying to overload the subscript operator -i know it as the element access operator- to take a char * or a std::string.

I have a struct

```
struct foo
{
    int Age;
    const char *Name;
};
```

and a std::vector that will be holding multiple instances of this struct.

```
std::vector<foo>bar;
```

my goal is to be able to access each foo in bar by calling them by their name.

```
std::cout<<"Simon's age is: "<<bar["simon"];
```

I've just been searching google for a long while trying to find an example or something to go off, with no luck.

i thought that this would work

```
foo operator[](char *Name)
{
    for(int i=0;i<bar.size();i++)
    {
        if(bar[i].Name == Name){return bar[i];}
    }
}
```

however apparently i'm doing something wrong

I do know this could be done with an std::map but i'd rather use an std::vector, thanks.

I would greatly appreciate your help however you choose to offer it. Thank you .

Comment: *"however apparently i'm doing something wrong"* - What's the error? We can't really help you without information

Comment: Is there any reason why you do not use a std::map, that offers just the functionality you are looking for ?

Comment: No, you cannot overload a subscript operator like that. You may want to create an `std::map` instead.

Comment: You almost certainly want to return a reference. And what happens if the name isn't found?

Comment: `operator[]` can only be defined as a member function. If you *really* want to do this, you would have to extend `std::vector` and override `operator[]`.

Comment: Consider: `std::map<std::string, foo> bar`. See: [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) and the example here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do what you want requires inheriting from std::vector.  Otherwise you can't overload its methods.

Something like the following (untested).

```
struct fooVector : public std::vector<foo> {
    typedef std::vector<foo> super;
    using super::size;
...
    foo& operator[](char const* Name) {
       super& self=*this;
       for(int i=0;i<size();i++)
       {
           if( ! strcmp( self[i].Name, Name) ){return self[i];}
       }
       // Need to do something reasonable if not found
    }
};
```

Comment: If you inherit from `std::vector` you still can't overload its methods. You can only overload the methods of *your* class. Inheriting from standard containers is not recommended.

Comment: @user3063807 If you aren't used to inheriting from a templated class, one big surprise will be that you can't simply use public or protected members of that class as `member` and have the compiler deduce the meaning as `this->member` (the way you could if the base class were not templated).  An example is my use of size() above.  There are several work arounds for that problem.  The best work around is what I showed with `using` in the above code.

Comment: @n.m. So far as I understand, inheriting from standard containers is "not recommended" for some very lame reasons, that almost never matter in the situations in which you would want to inherit from a standard container.  For example, if you inherit from any class that lacks a virtual destructor, you should not ever use a base class pointer to delete that derived class object.  But it is very common to have a derived class for which there is never any reason to support delete by base class pointer.

Comment: You can continue regarding these reasons as lame, everyone is entitled to have an opinion. A base class is a contract. You don't get to write it, you can only voluntarily accept it in its entirety. It says that whatever can be done with the base class object, can also be done with a derived class object through a base class pointer. If you don't want to adhere to the contract, do not inherit publicly. That's how we work in this OO paradigm. You are free to do whatever you want of course.

Answer (score 1):

```
bar[i].Name == Name
```

was probably meant to be

```
strcmp(bar[i].Name, Name) == 0
```

However, you'll be better off using `std::string`s than managing plain char pointers.

And instead of inheriting form a vector, create a class with a vector as a member and have your `operator[]` on that class.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there are some problems with your test:

1) you're using const char* for string type, comparing with == would likely fail as you're comparing two pointers and not their content. you need to use strcmp or better use std::string (c++ way)

2) what if your index operator would not find the value you're looking for?

I don't think this is a proper way of doing this but in case you really want to use vector you can inherit your own class and define new operator which uses const char* as a index argument:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

struct foo {
    int age;
    const char *name;
};

class MyVector : public std::vector<foo> {
public:
    const foo* operator[](const char* name) const {
        for (auto it=cbegin(); it != cend(); ++it) {
            if (strcmp(it->name, name) == 0) {
                return &(*it);
            }
        }
        return nullptr;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    foo foo1 = { 10, "abc" };
    foo foo2 = { 20, "test" };

    MyVector v;
    v.push_back(foo1);
    v.push_back(foo2);

    std::cout << "test: " << v["test"]->age << std::endl;
}
```

Although it's not generally advised to inherit from stl containers (they don't have virtual destructors), if you don't add any data attributes to inherited class you should be fine.

But I would suggest you to consider using std::map as a container and std::string as index / name attribute type. Searching vector has linear complexity but std::map has logaritmic complexity. Or you can consider using hash tables.