# "No match for operator []"

Tags: c++

I know similar issues have been asked before but I cant seem to solve my issue using the info from any of them.

**What I want to achieve:**
I have to implement a Table (PRTable) that holds PREntry objects. My implementation in c++ is as below

```
class PREntry{

  public:
    PREntry()
    {   
      Timestamp = 0;
      rd_or_wr = 0;                                                                                                   
      complete = 0;
      addr = 0;                                                                                                       
    }   
    PREntry(Addr addr, Tick ts, bool rd_wr, bool complete)
    {   
      Timestamp = ts; 
      rd_or_wr = rd_wr;                                                                                               
      complete = complete;
      addr = addr;                                                                                                    
    }   

    Tick Timestamp;
    bool rd_or_wr;                                                                                                    
    bool complete;
    Addr addr;

  private :
    PREntry& operator=(const PREntry& obj); 

};
```

And my PRTable is as below

```
class PRTable
{
  public:
    // Constructor
    PRTable(int number_of_PREs){
      m_number_of_PREs = number_of_PREs ;
      entry.assign(16, PREntry());
    }   

    // Destructor
    ~PRTable();

    std::vector<PREntry> entry;
    bool isComplete(MachineID mID);
    void insertRequest(Addr addr, MachineID mID, Tick ts, bool rd_wr, bool complete);
    void deleteRequest(MachineID mID);

    // Print cache contents
    void print(std::ostream& out) const;

  private:
//  PREntry *entry = new PREntry[m_number_of_PREs];
//  PREntry *entry[16];
    int m_number_of_PREs;
    PRTable& operator=(const PRTable& obj);
//    PREntry operator[](MachineID mID){return entry[mID];}
//    typedef std::map<MachineID,L1Cache_PRE> MachineIDMap;
//    MachineIDMap m_map;


};
```

And finally the .cc file

```
using namespace std;

bool
PRTable::isComplete(MachineID mID)
{
    return entry[mID].complete;
}

void
PRTable::insertRequest(Addr addr, MachineID mID, Tick ts, bool rd_wr , bool complete)
{
    PREntry pre(addr,ts,rd_wr,complete);
    entry[mID] = pre;
}

void
PRTable::deleteRequest(MachineID mID)
{
    entry[mID].complete = 1;
}
```

When I run the code I get a tirade of errors, but I feel the main issue is this error message :

```
build/X86_MOESI_NoMig_token/mem/ruby/structures/PRTable.cc:36:14: error: no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'std::vector<PREntry>' and 'MachineID')
  return entry[mID].complete;
```

After some research online I figured that the operator[] is not defined for an array of objects, which is why I decided to use vectors where the [] is already defined in the vector class.
Any help would be great. I would like to understand how a scenarios like this is usually designed and coded in c++

Comment: What is a machine id?

Comment: You didn't put an implementation of the function `operator=` in your `.cc` file. It's not going to get generated magically for you.

Comment: From your use of `entry` it seems that you should be using a [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) or [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) instead of a vector.

Comment: This is a part of a simulator called GEM5, wherein I am trying to add a structure. All other Data Structures you see there like MachineID are defined in other parts in the simulator

Comment: As for your error, you *do* include the header file in the source file?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Could you please explain why you think I should use a map ? Thing is there are only 4 processors and I need one entry per processor indexed by the proc ID. So my first thought was to use a simple array.
Also I do include the header file in the source file. yes

Comment: A `std::vector` is like an array. You use an integer value as a zero-based index into it. And as with an array you can easily go out of bounds if you're not careful. With a map type you *map* something to something else, like for example you can map a `MachineId` to a `PREntry`.

Comment: Also note that with a map class, if you access something which does not exist using the `[]` operator, then it will be created. A vector is by default empty, and any indexing into it will be out of bounds. Since you don't really seem to add anything to the vector, that's what will happen with you (if you make it so that a `MachineId` can be used as an index, which I don't recommend).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your above code the error is that the [] operator for vectors are not overloaded to accept the type of MachineID.

Comment: How do I do that? I am very new to c++

Comment: You can not inherently do this. See this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31675907/overload-vector-subscript-operator-to-take-a-char-or-string